# MFSK vs FSK: Why BER decreases increasing the symbols

Tags: digital-communications, fsk

My question is related to the performance of 2-FSK modulation scheme against M-FSK (M > 2). 
From the SNR vs BER curve it seems that as the number of tones (frequencies) increases the BER decrease for the same SNR compared to 2-FSK(pics attached). (I assume maintaining the same symbol duration)

[image]

As the number of tones increases the bandwidth increases but i can't figure out why the performance of MFSK also increases. 
At first glance i would say that the resilience to the noise should be the same as the 2-FSK.

Which is the benefit of using 2-FSK instead of M-FSK (M>2) given a fixed available bandwidth?

Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (I assume maintaining the same symbol duration)

nope! That is usually not the case, because it would be unfair – if you send the same number of symbols per second, you'd get twice as many bits per second using 4-FSK rather than 2-FSK.

Therefore, the comparison is typically done with *identical Bit Energy* rather than identical *Symbol duration* (which would be, for constant envelope signals, be equal to *identical symbol energy*).

Hence, with higher modulation order, you get less symbols per bit, and hence, for constant $E_b$ more $E_{sym}$.

Now, errors happen on a symbol level – and a Symbol Error Rate of $r$ doesn't imply a BER of $r$ – in fact, a wrong symbol has *at most* its worth in bits in wrong bits, but usually less (see: Gray code), so $\text{BER}\le\text{SER}$ generally holds, and one can in an uncorrelated noise scenario be *almost certain* that $\text{BER}<\text{SER}$.

Comment: Thanks Marcus,  i assumed the same symbol duration and i couldn't figure out why. But if i understood well the evaluation is done within the same bit energy which means that the symbol duration for the case  of  4-FSK is twice of  2-FSK, maintaining in this case the same bit rate. In such case the BER is lower as the symbol duration is longer.

Comment: jep! And because if, for example, one fourth of all symbols is wrong for 4-PSK, then _less_ than one fourth of the bits is, whereas for 2-FSK SER = BER!